# when adding uipageviewcontroller to uiview I can't scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm adding my `UIPageViewController` to a UIView, however when I do this like below, it adds the correct controller, however I can't scroll?

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let pageController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageOverlayPageViewController") as! PageOverlayPageViewController

    previewImageView.addSubview(pageController.view)
    pageController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the correct UIPageViewControllerDataSource methods? You should have "viewControllerBefore" and "viewControllerAfter". Here is a link to the apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdatasource

The data source works similarly to table view data sources and collection view data source. You should maintain an underlying array that holds the view controllers that you want the page view controller to scroll through.

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
  if let index = controllers.index(of: viewController), index > 0 {
    return controllers[index - 1]
  }

  return nil
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
  if let index = controllers.index(of: viewController), index < controllers.endIndex - 1 {
    return controllers[index + 1]
  }
  return nil
}
```

In this code, controllers is an array of UIViewControllers, initialized and populated at an earlier point, like in viewDidLoad()

Hope that helps

Comment: yes I have it works fine if I set the pageviewcontroller as initial view controller but not if I ass it to another viewcontroller